# Scheduler for Amazon ECS tasks

Tags: scheduling, amazon

We are developing several automated processes that run as docker containers in an AWS ECS cluster and we would like a way to schedule times and dates for these processes to run (some run once a day, others run multiple times in a day, some only run once a week). We've looked at several different ways to achieve this goal:

1. Jenkins (scheduling scripts that call the AWS cli to start the tasks)
2. Rundeck (same as above)
3. A server with cron (same as above)
4. Scheduled events in AWS CloudWatch that trigger Lambda functions that start the tasks

Does anyone have any insight or recommendations on what should be used here? Other software/solutions not listed above are welcome.